# What makes the Boost `interval_map` to ignore insertion?

Tags: c++, boost-icl

The code below is supposed to insert two intervals with associated values 0 and 1 into the Boost interval map, but it inserts only one:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>

using Interval = boost::icl::interval<int>;
using IMap = boost::icl::interval_map<int, int>;

int main()
{
  IMap m;
  m += std::make_pair(Interval::right_open(0, 7), 0);  // <== ignored?
  m += std::make_pair(Interval::right_open(8,15), 1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
{([8,15)->1)}
```

If I change the value for the "ignored" line to 1, it will insert the pair correctly.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any domain interval with "no value" has an implicit "0" in the co-domain. And vice versa. I guess the following sample would make sense immediately:

```
m += std::make_pair(Interval::right_open(8,15), 1);
m -= std::make_pair(Interval::right_open(8,15), 1);
```

Results in an empty map.

See [Map Traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/concepts/map_traits.html).

> Icl maps differ in their behavior dependent on how they handle identity elements of the associated type CodomainT.

Specifically under [Definedness and Storage of Identity Elements](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/concepts/map_traits.html#boost_icl.concepts.map_traits.definedness_and_storage_of_identity_elements)

> The second trait is related to the representation of identity elements in the map. An icl map can be a identity absorber or a identity enricher.
>
> - A identity absorber never stores value pairs (k,0) that carry identity elements.
> - A identity enricher stores value pairs (k,0).

Comment: I think the page https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/concepts/map_traits.html better describes what is going on with identity elements. You could update your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @HEKTO you're quite right. I remembered reading it and couldn't find that page. It's much better indeed.